# Where do dbml files go in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model

A lot of the samples I have seen put mock classes in the Model folder. If I am using Linq2SQL, should I just have my dbml files in the Model folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I did the same, in my opinion the Models folder is the best place. Actually, its just a mater of preference on how to organize your project files, it doesn't have anything to do with MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? When you use LinqToSql you will have the domain model and you can put in the Model folder, but therefore you can put in the separate dll. You should not put in the View or the ViewModel because in the ViewModel you will
put classes that present your domain model to the View. But I recommend to Use Entity FrameWork ORM

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linq-to-sql the linq-to-sql-generated entity classes are the model and the data context is the way to access them. The ViewModel exposes a bindable interface to the view and maps it to the corresponding linq-to-sql entity classes.

In my opinion this is an excellent architecture for many applications. There is a real mapping need between the view and the model which is handled. Very few applications actually benefit from having a model that is mapped to a different storage model, which is what Entity Framework is for.